# Google Play Games Leaderboard post score reports success but doesn't update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am using the google play games Unity3D api on Unity 2018.2.15f1, it should be noted that my google play games project isn't published however I don't want to publish it until I have all my achievements in there.

The leaderboard posting code is:

```
public void PostScore(long score)
{
    Social.ReportScore(score, GPGSIds.leaderboard_high_scores, (bool success) => {
    // handle success or failure

        if(success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Posted Score of " + score);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed to post score");
        }
    });
}
```

and logcat consistently shows that this returns a success, as so:

```
11-16 02:45:05.041: I/Unity(5503): (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 43)
11-16 02:45:05.042: I/Unity(5503): Posted Score of 19
```

However no matter what the leaderboard doesn't update, it consistently shows a score of 8. I don't understand why this is here as it shows up exclusively on my device even and even if I wipe the leaderboard it persists.

Is the issue with the fact that the leaderboard isn't published yet? Or could there be something else at play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was GPGS was caching the leaderboard scores and refusing to update them from the remote copy,  the solution was to modify the `IPlayGamesPlatform` interface to support passing in a custom `Types.DataSource` parameter. This allows for the option to view the cached and networked version or just the networked version.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answering your own question when you solved it. Always nice to see that. Secondly, I suspect this is what I'm seeing in my game. I had a feeling the behaviour I was seeing was a caching issue. What you've said pretty much confirms it. I'll try to implement your solution and hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 8):

In my case the problem got solved when I edited my GameServices profile and enabled the checkbox "Let others see your game activity".

Before that no matter what I did, all reported scores got ignored.

Comment: omg, that solved it^^ I was already asking myself what I did wrong^^